# np.linspace and stacking arrays

Tags: python

I am trying to implement something on the following lines, however, I get an error

```
v=np.linspace(0,2,10)
v_2=v**2
v_3=v**3


np.column_stack(v,v_2,v_3)
```

The error I get is:

`TypeError: _column_stack_dispatcher() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given`

I gogloode it but as I am an inexperienced programmer focused on mathematics, I did not understand the error, and its source. I would like someone to tell me what I should correct, in order for me to stack together different arrays generated by np.linspace.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`numpy.column_stack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html) takes only **one** argument, and it should be a tuple of arrays. That's why it is complaining of more than one arguments being passed. Pass your arrays in a tuple like this:

```
np.column_stack((v, v_2, v_3))
```